# netbeans installation error: can't initialize ui running in headless mode

Tags: netbeans, installation

I'm trying to install NetBeans on Linux Mint, and I'm getting the following error every time I run the installation script:

Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
Can`t initialize UI
Running in headless mode

What should I do to get it working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like Netbeans does not work properly with Openjdk. This is what I did (in Linux Mint 12):

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Then you will be able to run the `.sh` installer as usual.

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04 which no longer has the Sun JDK included.

Comment: For Fedora use: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone has this problem in the future, Netbeans doesn't like OpenJDK 6 but -- fortunately -- it works fine with OpenJDK 7 (as expected as for Java 7 OpenJDK is the reference implementation). Just make sure you remove any Java 6 packages before installation attempts. On Ubuntu and Mint one can do:

```
sudo apt-get purge ^openjdk-6-*
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

It should work afterwards.

Comment: I had to `sudo apt-get remove openjdk*` first, but other than that, works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

I hit this same issue on Kubuntu 12.04 LTS but needed Sun JDK 6 for a project I'm maintaining.  I stumbled upon Martin Wimpress' OAB-Java script (by way of [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)) which creates and installs a local apt repository for Sun JDK 6.  You can find the latest instructions on Martin's [github](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6) site which run as follows:

```
cd ~/
wget https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/raw/0.2.7/oab-java.sh \
-O oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh
```

If you want to see what this script is doing while it is running then execute the following from another shell:

```
tail -f ./oab-java.sh.log
```

Alternatively, you can clone the OAB-Java repo and kick of the script from within it:

```
git clone git://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6.git
cd oab-java6
sudo ./oab-java.sh
```

Either way, once that is in place follow Jose's instructions to remove openjdk and install sun jdk:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

One final note, the script accepts a `-7` argument which will create and install a local apt repository for Oracle JDK 7 should you want to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by getting into the target system using ssh -X, then making sure DISPLAY was exported.  That handles the X server issues.

Comment: and so you're able to run NB remotely, just viewing it, basically, through X server?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the priority of the Oracle Java executables:

   export PATH=/usr/java/latest/bin:$PATH
2. Run the installer:

   ./netbeans-8.1-linux.sh

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was installing default java environment from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Answer (score 0):

The installation was a success - under "user".

The installation failed - under "su" (under Red Hat equivalent of "sudo"). With

`` Can`t initialize UI
Running in headless mode
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it. ``
For me.

Comment: And the successful installation installed NetBeans' own jdk into /usr/java (my other jdks live in /usr/lib/jvm)