# Error While installing netbeans in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, netbeans-7, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to install netbeans 'netbeans-7.2.1-ml-linux.sh' on my ubuntu12.04

But when i am executing this .sh file i am gettig the exception given below.

```
 Configuring the installer...
 Searching for JVM on the system...
 Extracting installation data...
 Running the installer wizard...
 Can`t initialize UI
 Running in headless mode

 Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install Java Runtime Environment

```
sudo aptitude install default-jre
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this answer:

[netbeans installation error: can't initialize ui running in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607298/netbeans-installation-error-cant-initialize-ui-running-in-headless-mode/8780869#8780869)

Worked for me.  For some reason, with OpenJDK the installer was unable to open a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is the support of openJDK for the UI.
The solution is installing Oracle JDK, open your terminal and write the following commands:

*sudo apt-get remove openjdk**
*sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java*
*sudo apt-get update*
*sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer*
*sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default*

after that reinstall netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a X-Server for installation (`java.awt.HeadlessException`). The installation script needs a UI.

Comment: Install X with a window manager on your computer (GNOME/KDE/XFCE/LCDE/...)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the sh installer does not work with the openJDK 7. 
Quick fix to install is to change back to JDK 6. 
run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
(select java 6) 
sh netbeans-7.2.1-ml-linux.sh
```

the installer should run and then just switch back to the java 7 JDK with update-alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had openjdk installed, where `/usr/bin/java` was point to the installed openjdk.
I solved it by installing the Oracle JDK 7, from a tar.gz file. Extract the tar ball to a location say your $HOME directory.

After that
I modified the `.bashrc` file and modified the PATH variable to

> PATH=$HOME/jdk1.7/bin/:$PATH
>  export PATH

Remember the path to your jdk/bin should be appended to PATH, as as result the system will find the java executable in your path rather than picking the installed openjdk.

`Note:` I chose not to uninstall installed openjdk, as most of my Libreoffice and other installed applications were depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then default java

```
sudo apt-get install -f default-jre
sudo apt-get install -f default-jdk
```

And should be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it for me:

1. I installed the Java JDK. In this case:

   sudo aptitude install openjdk-8-jdk
2. Here's the kicker: I made sure that my Home and Path variables were set properly. Again, in my case:

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk

   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin

**My initial issue was not having the JDK installed. It was then not having the environment variables properly set.** If they aren't properly set, the installer won't launch. Simple as that.